# WARNINGS: ?: (mysql.W002)

Tags: mysql, django

I'm new to django, just wanted to change to MySQL databases, but this warning keeps how up even though I have already added the code for it.

My setting.py

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': "mysql_database",
        "USER": "root",
        "PASSWORD": "",
        "OPTION": {
            'init_command': "SET sql_mode='STRICT_TRANS_TABLES', innodb_strict_mode=1",
            'charset': 'utf8mb4',
            "autocommit": True,
        }

    }
}
```

The warning

```
WARNINGS:
?: (mysql.W002) MariaDB Strict Mode is not set for database connection 'default'
        HINT: MariaDB's Strict Mode fixes many data integrity problems in MariaDB, such as data truncation upon insertion, by escalating warnings into errors. It is strongly recommended you activate it. See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/databases/#mysql-sql-mode
```

Have tried resetting and migrating a couple of times, and it didn't work.

Comment: Try `OPTIONS` instead of `OPTION` ([docs](https://django-mysql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/checks.html))

Comment: Thank you, I tried it, and it works perfectly. But, I don't know how to accept your comment as correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the error message you've got, provides you an element of solution. if you go to that link https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/databases/#mysql-sql-mode you'll notice that it's `OPTIONS` (plural) and NOT `OPTION` (single):

> If you need to customize the SQL mode, you can set the sql_mode variable like other MySQL options: either in a config file or with the entry 'init_command': "SET sql_mode='STRICT_TRANS_TABLES'" in the **OPTIONS** part of your database configuration in **DATABASES**.

and as good coding practices, dictionaries are usually kept in plural like `DATABASES` or `OPTIONS`.